# C++: Getting a temporary file, cross-platform

Tags: c++, temporary-files

I'm looking for a cross-platform way of getting designated a temporary file. For example in linux that would be in the `/tmp` dir and in Windows in something akin to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Does a cross-platform (Boost?) solution to this exist?

**EDIT**:

I need this file to exist until the program terminates. `tmpfile()` does not guarantee that. Quoting from ccpreference:

> The temporary file created is automatically deleted **when the stream is closed (fclose)**  or when the program terminates normally.

Comment: Could you comment on how using `tmpnam` fails to suit your purposes?

Comment: @jwd: It doesn't - sorry, I forgot to accept an answer.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The [Boost Filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library, from version 3 of that library, can be used to create a [temporary file name](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#unique_path).  It also offers a crisp solution. Indeed, the following C++ code should be platform independent:

```
// Boost.Filesystem VERSION 3 required
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
boost::filesystem::path temp = boost::filesystem::unique_path();
const std::string tempstr    = temp.native();  // optional
```

The filesystem path object `temp` can be used to open a file or create a subdirectory, while the string object `tempstr` offers the same information as a string.

Comment: This should be accepted - `tmpnam` can be an attack vector.

Comment: unique_path only returns a filename. Use `boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / boost::filesystem::unique_path()` for a complete temporary pathname.

Comment: For those who are wondering: `unique_path()` won't be part of `std::filesystem` due to possible race condition, see https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/msg7747.

Comment: @MattClarkson This has exactly the same problems as `tmpnam()`.

Comment: Does someone know if it's safe with Windows 10's Storage Sense that can delete temporary files ?

Answer (score 8):

If you use Qt: [QTemporaryFile](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtemporaryfile.html) class is perfect.

Answer (score 7):

The standard C library contains a function called `tmpfile`, it probably does what you need: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpfile/

You can use it in C++ programs as well.

**EDIT:**
If you need only file name, you can use [`tmpnam`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpnam/), it doesn't delete the file when fclose is called. It returns full file path, including the temp directory.

The C way:

```
const char *name = tmpnam(NULL);  // Get temp name
FILE *fp = fopen(name, "w");  // Create the file
// ...
fclose(fp);
remove(name);
```

Comment: Same comment as on James': This is no solution for me. I need the guarantee of the file's existance until the exit of the program. Quoting from ccpreference: "The temporary file created is automatically deleted when the stream is closed (fclose)."

Comment: Using `tmpnam` means introducing a race condition, too.

Comment: tmpnam also does not work on C++14 compliant systems, like GCC 5.4 under MSYS2. I don't know what a "\s778." is for a temporary name except entirely incorrect for a Windows system. That would be a directory path, not a file path.

Comment: tmpnam doesn't exist on android

Comment: For those wondering what is meant that `tmpname` introduces a race condition, see this http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/06/creating-temporary-files-on-win32-in-c-part-1/

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17, you can use [std::filesystem::temp_directory_path()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path).

Comment: This does not help create a temporary file, it just gives you the name of a temporary folder. If you put a file in there it will remain.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the C Standard Library function `tmpfile`.

Comment: This is no solution for me. I need the guarantee of the file's existance until the exit of the program. Quoting from ccpreference: "The temporary file created is automatically deleted when the stream is closed (fclose)."

Comment: @nightcracker:  Ok... so don't close the file stream until you are done using the temporary file?

Comment: Won't that block access from external programs (that's the whole point, I need a temporary file for other programs to read)? I was thinking of using [tmpnam](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpnam/).

Comment: @nightcracker: how would the external programs know the name of the file to read? Are you sending it to them in some way? This feels like contradicting the idea of a temp file

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Espeically since you seem to like the idea of Boost, [Robbie Morrison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335566/567650) is probably better for you.

My original answer remains below, but anyone reading this: please beware that tmpnam is unsafe. Further, some platforms (such as Windows) may have broken, buggy, braindead, or even missing implementations.

---

How about [tmpnam](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpnam/), if you don't like tmpfile?

From the link:

> The file created this way, unlike
>   those created with tmpfile is not
>   automatically deleted when closed; You
>   should call remove to delete this file
>   once closed.

Especially if you need another program to know the name of the file, this seems more appropriate, since tmpfile doesn't give you a name at all.

I believe it is not as secure though, if that's a concern.
Here is a [link describing some of those issues](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/222683-tmpnam#post911380).

---

Aside: Even if you wanted to use tmpfile, you should consider the more secure [tmpfile_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile) (the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tmpfile?view=vs-2019) even go so far as to call tmpfile "deprecated" though I doubt it would be removed from the C++ standard any decade soon). Regardless, neither of those retain the named file, which you require.

Comment: From GCC on linux: warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp' -- But I guess that mkstemp is not crossplataform.

Comment: @André: `mkstemp` has the same problem as `tmpfile` with regard to the original question's constraints - it just gives you a file handle back. But you're right, `tmpnam` is insecure, as noted.

Comment: From debian documentation: BUGS Never use this function.  Use mkstemp(3) or tmpfile(3) instead.

Answer (score -7):

There are much better ways to communicate between programs than random temporary files. Could you use a pipe for the communication instead? What about using a localhost socket?

If you insist on using files, just have your program use a name, possibly based on startup time.

Comment: the OP asked how to create a temporary file in a cross-platform manner, not whether it was a good idea. This is not helpful.