# Safe use of std::tmpnam

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

so I am developing an application, which requires to create a file, write into it, call another program with that file is an input, and delete the file.

I looked for possible solution and one solution looks like this.

```
std::FILE* tmpf = std::tmpfile();
std::fputs("Hello, world", tmpf);
```

According to the documentation of [`std::tmpfile`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpfile), if either the file is closed manually, or the program exits in natural way, the file will be deleted. This looks like good solution with one exception. It looks messy (using C I/O, instead of C++ streams).

Another solution would be to use [`std::tmpnam`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam), which will generate unique file name.

```
std::string file_name = std::tmpname(NULL);
// (*)
std::fstream stream{file_name};
stream << "Hello World" << std::endl;
```

But there is a problem with this one too. If another program creates file with the same name, while my program is in `(*)`, we will both be doing operations on same file, which is certainly something I'd like to avoid.

C++ STL (still) does not support file system operations, like checking if file exists. I could use something like [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to check that, but since checking for file and creating it is not atomic, it would not solve anything. And I did not find C++ STL method of atomic operation, which would: Check if file exists, if not, open it, if yes, fail.

So, my question is, what is the right way of solving this problem? Did I miss something?

Comment: You may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586355/c-getting-a-temporary-file-cross-platform

Answer (score 3):

Your specification "...create a file, write into it, call another program with that file is an input, and delete the file." is incompatible with tmpfile(). For one thing, there is no (portable) way to get the file name from the FILE pointer you get from tmpfile(), secondly on POSIX platforms tmpfile() will typically delete the file from the directory before returning from tmpfile() (if you're unfamiliar with POSIX filesystem semantics, the file exists as long as your process has an open file descriptor to it even after it's deleted from the directory, meaning there is no way to access it from the filesystem).

Given that, you'll have to use some kind of tmpname() type approach, and figure out a way to prevent two processes from simultaneously accessing it (file locks, check link count with stat(), or such).

Or better yet, don't use files for interprocess communication. For the simplest possible(?) case, create a pipe in the parent, connect it to stdin of the child.

Comment: I have to execute another program which reads the input from list of files.

Comment: @Zereges: Oh well, sometimes real life isn't so pure and nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my almost not messy solution:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h> // libstdc++ specific

int main()
{
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> tmpfile_buf{std::tmpfile(), std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary};
    std::iostream tmpstream{&tmpfile_buf};

    // write in stream
    tmpstream << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    tmpstream.seekg(0);

    // read from stream
    std::string str;
    std::getline(tmpstream, str);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/894ee8ca08f99f7a)

`std::tmpfile()` is used and a stream is build from a buffer having an underlying `FILE*`. This is a GNU extension and thus not portable :(.

Comment: I won't use it since its not portable.

Comment: I'm sorry it is not, I'm still looking for Boost solutions but can't find some. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a Boost solution to suggest, but I can't test it here.

With a `FILE*` returned from `std::tmpfile()`, one can get a file descriptor:

```
#include <cstdio>
FILE* const tmpfile = std::tmpfile();
const int fd = ::fileno(tmpfile);
```

and at this stage, everything looks good to use [`boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html):

```
#include <boost/iostreams/code_converter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/maped_file.hpp>
file_descriptor_source tmpstream(fd, boost::iostreams::close_handle);
```