# Secure and cross platform mmap of temporary file

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, mmap

I'm trying to do the following in a way that works cross platform (Linux, Mac, Windows). This code snippet is Linux specific and error checking is omitted for brevity:

```
char filename[] = "tmpXXXXXX";
int fd = mkstemp(filename);
char *addr = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
unlink(filename);
[...]
do stuff with addr
[...]
munmap(addr, length);
close(fd);
```

The cool thing here are the following features:

1. the temporary file is created in a way that is secure in the sense that there is no race between checking whether the file exists and opening the file
2. should the process end early, the temporary file is automatically deleted thanks to an early `unlink()` while keeping the file descriptor open

I want to achieve the same thing in a way that works across multiple operating systems and not only on Linux. Especially the first item is important. The second is just practical but I can live without it.

The best solution for a cross-platform mmap I found was `boost::iostreams::mapped_file`. Unfortunately, it uses filenames and not filedescriptors as input. So I'd have to do:

```
char filename[] = "tmpXXXXXX";
int fd = mkstemp(filename);
boost::iostreams::mapped_file file(filename, boost::iostreams::mapped_file::readwrite, length);
unlink(filename);
[...]
do stuff with file
[...]
file.close();
```

But anything can happen with `filename` between `mkstemp()` and `mapped_file()`. For example another process could just replace the temporary file created with `mkstmep()` such that the file opened by `mapped_file()` will be a different one. This is exactly the problem that is supposed to be solved by `mkstemp()` by it atomically creating a new file and returning an open file descriptor. But this only works if the functions I use on that file can also take file descriptors as input.

The only workaround I came up with so far is to do something like this:

```
char filename[] = "tmpXXXXXX";
mkdtemp(dirname);
std::string filename = dirname + "/constant.bin"
boost::iostreams::mapped_file file(filename, boost::iostreams::mapped_file::readwrite, length);
unlink(filename);
[...]
do stuff with file
[...]
file.close();
rmdir(dirname);
```

So instead of creating a file, I create a directory (which is atomic) to which only I have access and then create a file with a known constant name inside of it. While this approach solves the race condition problem of the example above, it has the drawback of requiring an extra directory for each temporary mmap-ed file I want to create. Furthermore, I now have the problem that if my program terminates unexpectedly, then there will be stale directories leftover. This is because on Windows, the file will not be removed until after the call to `close()` and thus I can only `rmdir()` after it. So this workaround is not optimal.

So is there another cross platform wrapper of mmap that is actually able to use file descriptors? Or maybe there is a wrapper that also does the whole creation of a temporary file securely for me? But maybe I'm even looking for the wrong thing entirely because `mkstemp` doesn't seem to be portable either and according to [C++: Getting a temporary file, cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586355/c-getting-a-temporary-file-cross-platform) there doesn't seem to be a secure cross-platform alternative. The chosen answer uses `boost::filesystem::unique_path` which is known to suffer from the race condition that I want to avoid by using `mkstemp` on Linux.

So what to do? Do I have to give up and admit that this can only securely be done on POSIX systems?

Comment: Hmm... Just a quick thought - maybe you can leave the race condition but in a way that you can detect it (like try to open the file with an exclusive lock) and then if it fails, try again. The odds of it happening multiple times in a row are almost zero.

Comment: The native MS-Windows (WIN32API) takes a file handle (or can use the system page-file) `CreateFileMapping` followed by `MapViewOfFile` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why do you need to map an immediately-unlinked file instead of using an anonymous mapping that's backed by the system paging file?

Comment: @eryksun Because the system page file is not controlled by the user. A user might have a 100G home directory on a system with a maximum of 2G pagefile.

Comment: Are you willing to call the Windows API directly, as Richard suggested? If so you can open the file with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` and no shared access. When the file handle is closed, the file will be unlinked from the directory, but you can continue to use the mapping.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the suggestion! Yes, if that works that would nearly solve my problem. "Nearly" because the downside would be, that I would then have to maintain windows specific stuff in my code instead of just using an existing library like boost that takes care of this OS specific abstraction for me. Also "nearly" because I don't yet see a replacement of `mkstemp` on Windows.

Comment: `GetTempPath` returns the user's temp directory, which should (given the default temp directory in the user profile) take care of ensuring only the user, administrators, and SYSTEM have access. `GetTempFileName` returns a unique file in a directory based on a three-character prefix, 16-bit unique integer, and ".tmp" file extension (65535 names per directory and prefix). It checks that the file can be created by calling `CreateFile` with the `CREATE_NEW` disposition and no sharing, but it closes the handle instead of returning it.

Comment: You can use a function that loops until success. Get a temp filename and attempt to create it exclusively as a new file with generic read/write and delete access and flagged for delete-on-close. Create the file mapping and map it. If that succeeds, close the handle and return the address, else repeat.

Comment: Unlike your POSIX code above, the File handle must be closed in order to actually unlink the file from the directory. Windows does not support anonymous File objects. If you have delete access for a File object, then Windows does allow setting the underlying file (or stream) control block's delete disposition. In this case it's still present in the directory listing but can't be re-opened for any access. You can also unset the delete disposition to restore it. The filesystem can only unlink a 'deleted' file once every handle for every open File object that references the file has been closed.